# 'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: flutter, cmd

I added the route to the bin to the PATH but CMD still doesn't recognize it. I have Windows 10.
[echo %PATH%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHy5D.png);
[where the bin is located](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycsEA.png);

I tried to write flutter commands in CMD, but it gave "'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command" feedback

Comment: Instead of giving us the that output, please give us the output from ```set path```, you could also, optionally run this command, ```%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe flutter```.

Answer (score 0):

hi I think this link will help https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/200/flutter-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/
try reinstalling flutter too and then run this command => flutter doctor
and I suggest using git-bash instead of cmd

Comment: Hi, I have git installed. I also tried using flutter doctor on flutter.bat and it works.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to properties by right clicking computer icon.
- click on Advanced system settings. (left side of the window)
- opens Environment Variables
- double click on path
- Click on New and paste the path of the bin folder located in the flutter sdk folder.
  example : `C:\src\flutter\bin`
- Click OK OK and OK
- Restart your pc (Recommend)

Comment: Hi, I did it all already. Still doesn't work(

Comment: Did you check it is the correct bin path?